# On the isomorphism of the lattices of submodules of certain free modules

Tags: fields, lattice-theory, p-adic-numbers

Let $K,L$ be two finite extensions of the $p$-adic field
$\mathbb{Q}_p$ of the same degree. Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ and
$\mathcal{O}_L$ be the ring of integers of these two fields, and let
$\mathcal{O}_K^d$ be the free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module of rank $d$, and
similarly for $\mathcal{O}_L^d$. Finally let
$\mathfrak{L}(\mathcal{O}_K^d)$ be the lattice of
$\mathcal{O}_K$-submodules of $\mathcal{O}_K^d$ of finite colength,
and similarly for $\mathfrak{L}(\mathcal{O}_L^d)$.

When are $\mathfrak{L}(\mathcal{O}_K^d)$ and
$\mathfrak{L}(\mathcal{O}_L^d)$ isomorphic? The two extreme
possibilities are (1) they are always isomorphic, and (2) they are
isomorphic only when $K\cong L$.

This question arises in trying to characterize $\mathbb{N}$-graded
modular lattices $M$ with finitely many elements of each rank, such
that for all $t\in M$, the principal dual order ideal $V_t:=\{ s\in
M\colon s\geq t\}$ is isomorphic to $M$.

Comment: It's easy to check that the isomorphism type of this lattice retains $d$. Also for $d=1$ clearly it does not retain $K$ (this lattice is then reverse-isomorphic to $\mathbf{N}\cup\{\infty\}$).

Comment: For $d\ge 2$ it retains the cardinal of the residual field $k$. Indeed $O^d_k$ admits $k^2$ as quotient, which as lattice gives a max point, a min point, and $|k|+1$ points in between, and any quotient with a lattice of this form (1 max 1 min and $\ge 1$ points in between) has the form $k^2$. So (1) is excluded, and the replacing extreme would (for $d\ge 2$) be (1') they are isomorphic iff the residual fields have the same cardinal.

Comment: When d=2, the lattice only retains the information about the residue field. For larger d, I suspect you can reconstruct the field K. Lattices are verticies in the building of GL_n(K), and there are classification theorems about affine buildings, which I believe enable one to reconstruct the field if the rank is not too small. Since I don't know the details of these results, I choose to make a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @PeterMcNamara: Bjorn Poonen made a similar comment when I showed the problem to him, but can someone provide the details?

Comment: I just wanted to record in a comment that I am thinking about this problem, and I have some suspicions that - contrary to suggestions above - the isomorphism type of the lattice should only depend on $d$ and $q=p^a$, the cardinality of the residue field. My guess is that the interval between the minimum and the join of atoms should be isomorphic to the lattice of $\mathbb{F}_q$-subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_q^d$, and then the rank generating function of the infinite lattice will be $((1-x)(1-qx)\cdots(1-q^{d-1}x))^{-1}$ (see https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.12103). This may be true for any DVR.